# MINIX 3.3.0: How do I add a new command binary?

Tags: c, makefile, minix

I am trying to make a new command in the src/bin folder as a test (called "tcom" for test command, not to be confused with "test" command). I already tried editing src/bin/tcom/Makefile to add the program name and src/bin/Makefile to include the program name.

However, it's never there when I build Minix. Is there anything I need to include in the command source code (written in C)? Any other Makefile references?

src/bin/tcom/tcom.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    (void)printf("Hello World!");

    return 0;

}
```

src/bin/tcom/Makefile

```
#   $NetBSD: Makefile,v 1.9 1997/07/20 22:36:37 christos Exp $
#   @(#)Makefile    8.1 (Berkeley) 5/31/93

PROG=   tcom
SRCS=   tcom.c

.include <bsd.prog.mk>
```

src/bin/Makefile

```
#   $NetBSD: Makefile,v 1.22 2007/12/31 15:31:24 ad Exp $
#   @(#)Makefile    8.1 (Berkeley) 5/31/93

#__MINIX: chio mt ps

SUBDIR= cat chmod cp csh date dd df domainname echo ed expr hostname \
    kill ksh ln ls mkdir mv pax ps pwd rcp rcmd rm rmdir sh \
    sleep stty sync tcom test \

.include <bsd.subdir.mk>
```

(ported over from minix3 group because people are more likely to answer here)

Comment: You should probably add more details to show us *exactly* what you tried.

Comment: Added source code to the question

Answer (score 0):

Your command is probably built, but not installed in the destination tree. You should probably add it to `distrib/sets/lists/minix-base/mi` for a start (and minix-debug if it applies). Also consider locating your code in `src/minix/bin` if it is MINIX-specific; `src/bin` is more appropriate for NetBSD inherited code.